# What code should I use to display children of a custom post?

Tags: custom-post-types, child-pages

I have a hierarchical custom post type, and on each single view of a post of this type I want to display the title of the children of this post, outside of the loop.

The code I'm currently using is below, and it works - but I've no idea whether it's a sensible way to do it or if there's other options.

```
$pageChildren = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID."&echo=0&post_type=show");
if ( $pageChildren ) {
    foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
        echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '">'. $pageChild->post_title.'</a></p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: What if a child of child is there ?

Comment: @cjbj - thanks, that's encouraging; it's code I found elsewhere.

Comment: @Sumit - thanks, I hadn't thought of that; do you have suggestions please?

Comment: You can use `wp_list_pages()`!

Comment: @Sumit... thanks. Most of this is beyond my knowledge, but with wp_list_pages() wouldn't I have to include 'child_of' to specify the parent? I need something dynamic which can be added to the single-cptname template and work for all such posts.

Comment: @gulliver you can pass the parent  ID in `child_of` to get the all child elements. Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by dynamic? This is dynamic.

Comment: @Sumit... thanks. Sorry for the confusion - my understanding of this is much less than I'd like. I thought  wp_list_pages() had to have the id of a specific page/post, and hence wouldn't work if added to the single template of a cpt. I read in the Codex: 'child_of'... display the sub-pages of a single page by ID. So that's why I can't understand how I can use it in a single template for posts of a cpt.

Comment: @gulliver I posted an example :)

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_list_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) calls [`get_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) internally and pass the argument list to `get_pages` so you can pass arguments whatever `get_pages` accept.

To display child posts on your `single-{post_type}.php` you need to call `wp_list_pages` with `post_type` parameter.

`wp_list_pages` will ignore `post_type` but it will pass this to `get_pages`.

Example:-

```
echo '<ul>';

wp_list_pages(array(
    'post_type' => 'show',
    'child_of' => get_the_ID(),
    'title_li' => false //Set to false to disable the heading
));

echo '</ul>';
```

The only benefit of using `wp_list_pages` is hierarchical display in case if you have grandchildren of a post. `get_pages` with `foreach` loop will always give you flat list regardless of child or grandchild.

Comment: thanks, appreciated. I'm beginning to understand this stuff much better now.